# awk transpose including empty fields into csv

Tags: csv, awk, null, transpose

I'm trying to get a handle on awk but am stumped on how to transpose this data and include the nulls of the first two fields ie repeating the value. ie name and osType only occur once for each host instance.

Having a null in the additional lines causes issues... Is there a way to repeat the host name e.g. "SDC1NM519" and ostype "Windows" for each null in the following rows?

It would be also handy to understand how to add/remove additional rows if needed as well.

this is the data i have:

```
>cat tmp2.txt |pg
name    SDC1NM519
osType  Windows
displayName     00:60:04
capacityInKB    1,048,576
consumedCapacityInKB    43,008
dpPoolID        10
displayName     00:60:08
capacityInKB    1,335,885,824
consumedCapacityInKB    370,944,000
dpPoolID        10
displayName     00:F0:1A
capacityInKB    102,400
consumedCapacityInKB    43,008
dpPoolID        10
name    SDC1NM518
osType  Windows
displayName     00:00:18
capacityInKB    78,643,200
consumedCapacityInKB    3,655,680
dpPoolID        30
```

I need to be able to produce the $2 and $3 data from the rows into columns after each 'name' (host) and 'ostype' (eg Windows) in csv type format. I cant use (,:) as separators as the data includes them so either (tab or ;).

```
name;osType;displayName;capacityInKB;consumedCapacityInKB;dpPoolID
SDC1NM519;Windows;00:60:04;1,048,576;43,008;10
SDC1NM519;Windows;00:60:08;1,335,885,824;370,944,000;10
SDC1NM519;Windows;00:60:64;1,048,576;86,016;10
SDC1NM519;Windows;00:FE:03;1,048,576;43,008;10
SDC1NM518;AIX;00:FE:02;1,048,576;43,008;10
SDC1NM518;AIX;00:FE:03;1,048,576;43,008;10
SDC1NM518;AIX;00:F0:1A;102,400;43,008;10
SDC1NM518;AIX;00:00:18;78,643,200;3,655,680;30
```

Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is simple. Capture all the values as they're seen. Prior to capture print the output line whenever the input line starts with "displayName" (except for the first time) and also at the very end after the capture is done.

```
begin { print "name;osType;displayName;capacityInKB;consumedCapacityInKB;dpPoolID" }

\^displayName\ && displayName != "" {
    print name ";" os ";" display ";" capacity ";" consumed ";" pool
}

\^name\                 { name     = $2 }
\^osType\               { os       = $2 }
\^displayName\          { display  = $2 }
\^capacityInKB\         { capacity = $2 }
\^consumedCapacityInKB\ { consumed = $2 }
\^dpPoolID\             { pool     = $2 }

end {
    print name ";" os ";" display ";" capacity ";" consumed ";" pool
}
```

Or you could use an array and pick up the values in a simpler pattern:

```
begin { print "name;osType;displayName;capacityInKB;consumedCapacityInKB;dpPoolID" }

\^displayName\ && a["displayName"] != "" {
    print a["name"] ";"
          a["os"] ";"
          a["displayName"] ";"
          a["capacityInKB"] ";"
          a["consumedCapacityInKB"] ";"
          a["dbPoolID"]
}

{ a[$1] = $2 }

end {
    print name ";" os ";" display ";" capacity ";" consumed ";" pool
}
```

You refer to $2 and $3 in your question. I guess you'll know how to make the appropriate substitutions if necessary. You could probably find a way to avoid the duplicate print actions if the DRY thing bothers you.

Comment: Thanks Shawn, i'll have to give it a go, i'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Hi Shawn.. sorry for the delay in response but this doesn't appear to work, but its more likely my implementation rather then your code. Where do i reference the data file? Or do i put this after the commands to obtain the data.. if so how would i output it ">>" to a file? directly after the "end {} >> ouput.txt"  Statement??

Comment: The easiest is usually to redirect stdout at the command line. I think some implementations of awk have an argument for an output file too. You can do it in the print statements inside the script as well.